# How to reshape a big array (Memory Error)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a very big 6D array as `(225, 97, 225, 32, 32, 32)`. I want to reshape it into 4D array like `(225*97*225, 32, 32, 32)`. I tried to used python 2.7 in ubuntu 14.04 with bellow code but I got the memory error. How could I solve it? Thanks

```
import numpy as np

#input_6D shape (225, 97, 225, 32, 32, 32)
input_4D= input_6D.reshape(input_6D.shape[0]*input_6D.shape[1]*input_6D.shape[2], input_6D[0],input_6D[1],input_6D[2])
```

The error is

> input_4D= input_6D.reshape(input_6D.shape[0]*input_6D.shape[1]*input_6D.shape[2], input_6D[0],input_6D[1],input_6D[2])
>   MemoryError

This is step what I did. First, I load a 3D input with shape `256x128x256`. Then I used the code bellow to got 6D array as `(225, 97, 225, 32, 32, 32)` where patch shape is `32, 32, 32`

```
def patch_extract_3D(input,patch_shape):
    patches_6D = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(input, ((input.shape[0] - patch_shape[0] + 1) // xstep, (input.shape[1] - patch_shape[1] + 1) // ystep,
                                                  (input.shape[2] - patch_shape[2] + 1) // zstep, patch_shape[0], patch_shape[1], patch_shape[2]),
                                                  (input.strides[0] * xstep, input.strides[1] * ystep,input.strides[2] * zstep, input.strides[0], input.strides[1],input.strides[2]))
```

Comment: With this huge amount of data, you'll probably have to dump it to disk (file or database) first, and read it again.

Comment: Have you provide any solution by code? Sorry I did not catch full your solution

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same command you show in the question? Because to my eye it looks like you won't get as far as MemoryError with that command. You should get something like "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars", because you give as arguments to reshape things like `input_6D[0]`, which are not numbers but huge arrays themselves.

Comment: @user3051460: My comment was just, well, a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's seems that your input is at least 400 Go. How is it possible ?

Comment: @B.M. Let see my update to know how can I generate 6D array

Comment: `as_strided` creates a view.  But almost any action on it, including this reshape, makes a copy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35805797/901925 tries to explain why the reshape creates a copy.

Answer (score 0):

The strided expression works with `xstep,ystep,zstep=1,1,1`.

if input is `np.zeros((256,128,256),np.int8)` with strides `(32768, 256, 1)`, the output will have the given shape and strides `(32768, 256, 1, 32768, 256, 1)`.

I calculate that the strides for the reshaped array will have to be `(1426325504, 58982400, 262144, 1024, 32, 1)`.

There's no way to get that without a copy.  `as_strided` produces a view of the original. But the reshape will make a copy that is some 200x bigger.

More on creating a copy from an `as_strided` at [reshaping a view of a n-dimensional array without using reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803970/reshaping-a-view-of-a-n-dimensional-array-without-using-reshape)

This strided view might work with a reduction operation, such as taking the mean or sum on the last 3 dimensions.  Do that first, and then try to reshape.  `as_strided` is tricky, and doubly so when done on 3 dimensions.

[How to recover 3D image from its patches in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42434095/901925) - your previous question involving this striding code.